# Autowiring in case of Constructor with parameters for socket

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autowired

My main code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "DataSource.xml");
    App app = applicationContext.getBean(App.class);
    app.start();
}
```

And my start method

```
public void start() {

    try {
        ServerSocket mobCom = new ServerSocket(9846);
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        while (true) {
            Socket socket = mobCom.accept();
            PortService portService = new PortService(socket);
            executorService.submit(portService);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But I want the PortService object to be created from Spring and not directly since it has db classes for communication. How do I do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this in the past by doing this -

Implement a factory class for your PortService.

```
@Service
public class PortServiceFactory {
    private SomeObject someObject;

    @Autowired
    public PortServiceFactory(SomeObject someObject) {
        this.someObject = someObject;
    }

    public PortService getPortService(Socket socket) {
        return new PortService(someObject, socket);
    }
}
```

Autowire this factory in your class where you have that start() method.

Replace

```
PortService portService = new PortService(socket);
```

with

```
PortService portService = portServiceFactory.getPortService(socket);
```